# Iptables exclude subnet from limitations

Tags: iptables

I've set up limitations with command:

> iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -i venet0 --dport 80 -m limit --limit
>   25/minute --limit-burst 100 -j ACCEPT

How can I exclude one subnet from this limitation? I want to unlimited connections from subnet.

Comment: Insert a rule before this one where you specify the subnet and jump to ACCEPT. Life can be that easy.

Answer (score 2):

You could try 2 things, to exclude subnet 192.168.0.0/16 execute the following command

```
# iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -i venet0 ! -s 192.168.0.0/16 --dport 80 -m limit --limit 25/minute --limit-burst 100 -j ACCEPT
```

the second one if you need exclude more then one subnets

```
# iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -i venet0 -s 192.168.0.0/16 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
# iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -i venet0 -s 172.16.0.0/12 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
# iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -i venet0 -s 10.0.0.0/8 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Also you could use RETURN instead of ACCEPT. It would be depend on your policy.